# Returning latest date of column range matching cell criterion in spreadsheet

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Example spreadsheet data provided below:

| Date | Item | Event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22-01-01 | A | X |
| 22-02-01 | B | Y |
| 22-03-01 | C | X |
| 22-04-01 | A | X |

Using this data, I would like to create a table showing the latest date of each item with event `X` in this format:

| Item | Latest X |
| --- | --- |
| A | 22-04-01 |
| B | None |
| C | None |

The cells in the `Latest X` column are where I'd need to put the formulae, while the cells under `Item` are manually added.

`VLOOKUP` doesn't work here. If the criteria are that the value of the `Item` column must be associated with a `X` event (specific event, manually set), and the search array is the first table above, the expected data won't get returned.

Perhaps some sort of `MAX` formula, where a range meets the aforementioned criteria? Sounds like I'd need to get into arrays to figure this one out, but I'm not familiar with how they work just yet. So some sort of "If ITEM = A & EVENT = X, return the latest (MAX) date from range A2:A5"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace "Latest X" in header with X and use IF() and MAXIFS() in formula like this:

```
=IF(MAXIFS($A$2:$A100;$B$2:$B100;$E2;$C$2:$C100;F$1)=0;"None";MAXIFS($A$2:$A100;$B$2:$B100;$E2;$C$2:$C100;F$1))
```

[image: Example]

Or use [**Pivot Table**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/12090102.html):

[image: Example2]

Comment: The former works great. I've substituted the example columns for my actual spreadsheet columns like so: `=IF(MAXIFS($A$4:$A$500,$J$4:$J$500,AP4,$K$4:$K$500,"String")=0,"None",MAXIFS($A$4:$A$500,$J$4:$J$500,AP4,$K$4:$K$500,"String"))`. But because I add entries on a daily basis, I'd have to manually edit the max range of the formula each time, from 500 to 1000, and so on. My solution in other columns is `OFFSET(A$4,0,0,$A$2)` in place of `$A$4:$A$500`, where `$A$2` is a cell that counts the total number of rows. But applying it to this formula gives me a 502 error. Any idea why?

Comment: What about `$A:$A` instead `$A$4:$A$500` or `OFFSET(A$4;0;0;$A$2;1)`?

Comment: The spreadsheet layout won't permit the former, and the latter still shows the same error

Comment: What's wrong with Spreadsheet Layout? Confuse lines above A4? I don't think they will affect MAXIFS(). 502 error is Invalid argument - maybe A2 is not a number? Or is there an error elsewhere for the original formula? Please show the whole formula or ask a question at [ask.libreoffice](https://ask.libreoffice.org/c/english/5) - there you can discuss the problem in detail

Comment: Seems to be so. `$A:$A` gives the same error. I'll do some research on my own about it, and if required, I'll ask a separate question if need be. But for now, the original question was answered, so thanks. Hopefully for the second part, you've already nudged me in the right direction.